# How to make the VJET plugin fully working in eclipse for my node.js project

Tags: javascript, eclipse

VJET is almoust working for me, I can get code completion in the same file and for basic Node.js  modules (using NodejsTL) but for new modules(my modules) or modules installed with npm an increasing number of errors plagues my "Problems" tab in Eclipse. It is there any way to have clean "builds" and get rid of all warnings and errors?

Answer (score 1):

Vjet currently doesn't understand user defined modules. There are a three solutions to fix this... (1)a type library can be added to support more modules. (2)Vjet can be extended to support npm modules there is a enhancement request open for this. (3)There is a way to disable errors and warnings as well. You can provide disable errors and warnings at the project or workspace level. See preferences -> vjet -> code compliance -> errors and warnings. Thanks for the feedback.

Here is the enhancement request you should vote for to get VJET to understand nodejs user defined modules - https://www.ebayopensource.org/jira/browse/VJET-88